# How do you install a Appcelerator Titanium Module in OSX

Tags: titanium

I cannot find any instructions on how to install modules into Titanium

I have downloaded a trial version of the TVOut module from the Appcelerator webpage

https://developer.appcelerator.com/package/28/tv-out/media

however it doesn't say how to install this into Titanium?

I know it needs to end up in /Library/Application Support/Titanium/Modules but just unzipping into this location is not enough.

What is the command line script which I can run on the zip which will allow me to use it?

thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[here](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+Titanium+Modules) are the guides. if you build your module successfully you need to put the zip in root/Library/Application Support/titanium/. (not /users/name/Library/..). you need to add the module within your tiapp.xml like that

```
    ....
    <modules>
        <module version="0.1">nameOfYourModule</module>
    </modules>
</ti:app>
```

now the titanium preprocessor should build your module while building your project.

Comment: thanks, the thing I found frustrating was that I am not developing a module but want to purchase one that appcelerator are selling, but there is little or no documentation regarding installation. The guides they provide (your link) are for developers writing modules. Your instructions are exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT - In Titanium Studio, just go to Help > Install Mobile Module...

This brings up a dialog that lets you browse your filesystem for the module file.  Find the zip file inside the downloaded module folder ( example: ti.imagefactory-iphone-1.1.1.zip ) and it should work magically.

This is the most up to date guide for using and installing modules:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Using_a_Module

Answer (score 3):

You can also read complete instructions here:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+Titanium+Modules

Comment: That's for older versions (by now). It's similar but maybe not correct in all details.